# Ajax submit form : datas no longer sent in my onbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I'm using a zapier webhook to collect datas (and send it by email) from my form bootstrap.
Then I deal with AJAX to redirect the URL.
From now, when i submit the form, the redirect works properly, i receive the email but without data in it.
This is the code of the form :

```html
 <form id="embarq-form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="prenom"><p>Prénom</p></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenom" placeholder="Bob" name="prenom" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nom"><p>Nom</p></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" placeholder="Sponge" name="nom" required>
                  </div>
```

And the ajax one :

```js
 <script>
    $('#embarq-form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/2588268/z2mzj1/',
            type:'post',
            data:$('#embarq-form').serialize(),
            success:function(){
              // Redirect to another success page
              window.location = "/";
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Do you know a way to fix this in order to receive data input ?
Thanks.